# ASP.NET C# GridView Tab Index issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It seems that when adding a row to an ASP.NET GridView, the Tab Index does not behave as expected (or desired). Instead of tabbing across each column in a row and then moving to the next row, the tab will move down each row in a column and then move to the next column and so on. Simply put, it will tab vertically instead of horizontally. This can be an issue for data entry applications where a user relies heavily on keyboard input.

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been screwing with this for a while and have this solution! Hope it helps other people who have the same issue.

```
protected void theGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTabIndexes();
}


private void SetTabIndexes()
{
    short currentTabIndex = 0;
    inputFieldBeforeGridView.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;

    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in theGridView.Rows)
    {
        DropDownList dropDown1 = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("dropDown1");
        dropDown1.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;

        TextBox inputField1 = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("inputField1");
        inputField1.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;

        TextBox inputField2 = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("inputField2");
        inputField2.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex; 

        TextBox inputField3 = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("inputField3");
        inputField3.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;
    }

    someLinkAfterGridView.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Automatically create TabIndex in a repeater](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/automatically-create-tabindex-in-a-repeater/)

For each control you could set the TabIndex to a property in code behind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server">
  <columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" Visible="true"> 
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbGroup" Checked="true" runat="server" TabIndex='<%# TabIndex %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </columns>
</asp:GridVeiw>
```

Then in code behind increment a TabIndex counter:

```
private int _tabIndex = 0;

public int TabIndex
{
  get
  {
    _tabIndex++;
    return _tabIndex;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 clean and elegant solution, thanks for including and giving credit to original author.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the TabIndex's for all your controls inside the grid manually on the rowdatabound event.  Figure out how many controls you want to tab though on a specific row and then based on the row index just formulate the tab order.

Comment: exactly! This was more a question to get out there for others who may be google-ing this issue. I couldn't find anything out there. So here it is!